# How to change no data value from -32768 to -3.40282e+38 in raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, nodata

I am trying to change the null values of a raster from -32768 to -3.40282e+38 in QGIS. 
I tried using warp tool setting the no data values to my desired number but it did not change it.
Then I used the translate tool and didn't change it either... 
I tried using r.null to in grass and it change it to 2.14748e+09
I don't know another method or what should I try to change?

Comment: You could try QGIS raster calculator, first get rid of NoData value then change < 32000 to your intended value then set nodata value to intended value..

Comment: To elaborate on @MichaelMiles-Stimson; to get rid of no data you can use reclaissify

Comment: You should take a look at your raster data type (-32768 look like 16bit signed integer, 2.14748e+09 will suite 32bit integer - those are extreme values for those datatypes). Value of -3.40282e+38 requires sth much bigger than regular integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this **test** raster (20x20), with values between 1 and 50, I replaced 19 value by -32768 value.

[image]

In the following raster, the -32768 values were replaced by -3.40282e+38 values (see window of Value Tool Plugin):

[image]

The used expression is in the window of "Raster calculator expression" (below image and code sample):

[image]

```
("null_values@1"=-32768)*(-3.40282e+38)+("null_values@1"!=-32768)*("null_values@1")
```

These changes were verified with Value Tool Plugin (below image). Blue areas have the original values of **test** raster.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! It was really useful
I have one more question... what does the "!" sign mean in the expression?

Comment: The operator != means: 'different to', 'not equal to'. In this context: "if the cell of raster is different of -32768 then multiply one (because is TRUE) by the corresponding cell raster value".